# How to cast a character to int in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, functional-programming, lisp

How to cast a character to int in Clojure?

I am trying to write a rot 13 in clojure, so I need to have something to cast my char to int. I found something called (int), so I put:

```
(int a)
```

Get: CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: a in this context, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:13:1)

Then I put:

```
(int 'a)
```

Get: ClassCastException clojure.lang.Symbol cannot be cast to `java.lang.Character  clojure.lang.RT.intCast (RT.java:1087)

Then:

```
(rot13 ''a')
```

Get: ClassCastException clojure.lang.PersistentList cannot be cast to java.lang.Character  clojure.lang.RT.intCast (RT.java:1087)

And:

```
(rot13 "a")
```

Get:

```
ClassCastException java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Character  clojure.lang.RT.intCast (RT.java:1087)
```

So what is the right way to do it?

btw, I always get confused with all these clojure syntax. But I can never find any source only help me with my problem. Any suggestions? Thank you!!

Comment: I believe you are looking for a ["character literal"](http://clojure.org/reader) such as `\a` (the error message says it wants a Character, not an integer).

Comment: Thank you! That solves my problem. First time on stackoverflow and this is a good place!

Comment: Use the [documentation](http://clojure.org/documentation), particularly regarding the [reader](http://clojure.org/reader).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you are looking for is a character literal `\a`. A character literal is denoted by a single character, or 16-bit unicode code point, prefixed by the `\` reader macro.

```
(int \a) ;; => 97

(int \0) ;; => 48

(int \u0030) ;; => 48
```

With `(int a)`, `a` is a symbol. As such, the runtime tried and failed to resolve what that symbol was bound to.

With `(int 'a)`, `a` is also a symbol, but, because you declared it a symbol with the single quote (`'`), the runtime took it literally and tried and faild to cast the `clojure.lang.Symbol` to a `java.lang.Character`.

With `(rot13 ''a')`, `'a'` declares `a'` as a symbol. But, the extra `'` prefixing it makes the runtime treat the expression that declared the `a'` literally. `'a'` expands to `(quote a')`, so the "literal literal", `''a'`, expands to the list `(quote a')`.

```
''a' ;; => (quote a')

(second ''a') ;; => a'
```

With `(rot13 "a")`, `a` is a string. Strings cannot be cast to characters, but they can be treated as collections of characters. So, `(rot13 (first "a"))` would work as intended.

Comment: Thank you! That definitely helps!

Comment: Just realize that you edited later and had more stuff. This cleared all my questions about data time. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Clojurescript: (.charCodeAt "a") => 97

Answer (score 24):

Clojure will convert characters to int automatically if you ask nicely. It will convert it using ascii equivalence (well unicode in fact).

```
(int \a);;=>97
(int \b);;=>98
(int \c);;=>99
```

However, if you want to convert a Clojure char that is also a number to an int or long :

```
(Character/digit \1 10) ;; => 1
(Character/digit \2 10) ;; => 2
```

A non-digit char will be converted to `-1` :

```
(Character/digit \a 10) ;;=> -1
```

Which is ok in this case, since `\-1` is not a character.

```
(Character/digit \-1 10);;=>java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported character: \-1
```

It could be convenient also to note that `-` would convert to `-1`, although I wound not rely on it too much :

```
(Character/digit \- 10);;=>-1
```

The second parameter is obviously the base. Ex :

```
(Character/digit \A 16);;=>10
```

Comment: `(Character/digit \101 10) ;;=> 101` should error out, since `\101` is not a valid character (and it certainly isn't a digit). It does for me: 
```> (Character/digit \101 10)
Syntax error reading source at (REPL:89:43).
Unsupported character: \101  ```

Comment: @Jun-DaiBates-Kobashigawa correct, I'll remove this from my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Not sure why the long discussions above.

```
(Integer/parseInt s)
```

Comment: I think `Integer/parseInt` takes a string, throwing an exception if passed a character.