# Character to Integer in Clojure

Tags: clojure

How can one change a character literal into a number in Clojure, especially in a vector?

So, `[\1]` into `[1]`, or `\1` into `1`.

**Edit:**

Even better, how would one turn `[[3 \1] [2 \2] [1 \3]]` into `[[3 1] [2 2] [1 3]]`?

Comment: Have you checked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19749624/how-to-cast-a-character-to-int-in-clojure

Comment: Thanks, yeah, I saw it and just looked again, but didn't really find a  answer other than "read the docs about the reader," which I also looked over but haven't really understood yet. I don't really understand how character literals work. Like `(int \1) ;=> 49` ...  Meanwhile the best I've got so far is something like `(Integer. (str \1)) ;=> 1`

Comment: Actually the second answer to the question Eduardo linked to – posted by nha – addresses your question precisely: `(Character/digit \0 10)` → `0`.

Comment: Aha! Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already explained [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33157929/1327651) how to do the char conversion.

Regarding your edit, one way to do it is the following :

```
;; using destructuring
(map (fn[[n c]] [n (Character/digit c 10)] )  [[3 \1] [2 \2] [1 \3]])
```